# Monitor specific activity logs to trigger Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring

Usecase: Trigger Azure Function only for predefined Azure activity logs.

I tried to configure Azure Activity logs and Export to Event Hub, but it won't allow Filter set on it. As per [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-logs-stream-event-hubs), the filter settings do not have an impact on export settings.

My usecase is to trigger an Azure Function only for a specific set of activity logs (say VM, VNet, NSG Create/Delete/Modify).  What other Azure services can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

One option, but with some constraints, is to create [Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview) at Resource Group level or even for specific resources. Alerts provide some flexibility in filtering specific events for which you would want to trigger an Action, say an Azure Func in your case.

I was thinking Azure Logic Apps would do this as well. However, to my surprise I could not find an option to add Activity Log as a trigger. Probably, it would come in the future. As Azure is updated quite frequently, keep checking every now and then to see if you get any new options to do this.